# Load spring properties from library module properties file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-properties

I have a spring application where I have created a library module for accessing AWS Cognito that are going to be used by multiple applications.
The service needs a couple of properties in order to work which will be the same everywhere.
So I would like to have the properties file in the library module and force the properties to be loaded from there whenever the library is imported.

I have tried creating a file called `cognito-properties.yml` in the library's resource folder and created a configuration file that is supposed to read from it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = CognitoService.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:/cognito-properties.yml")
public class CognitoConfiguration {
    @Value("${cognito.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${cognito.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Bean
    public AWSCognitoIdentityProvider awsCognitoIdentityProvider() {
        return AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
            .withRegion(Regions.EU_NORTH_1)
            .build();
    }
}
```

But I can't get the properties to load from the properties.yml file in the library.
When I add the properties to the applications application.yml file it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that you can't use @PropertySource with a yml file.
It needs to be a .properties file.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use yml file Try using this

```java
@PropertySource(value = "${secrets.filePath}", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class ClassToLoadProperty {}
```

```java
@Configuration
@Component
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory extends DefaultPropertySourceFactory {
    public YamlPropertySourceFactory() {}
    
    public PropertySource createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        if (resource == null) {
            return super.createPropertySource(name, resource);
        } else {
            List<PropertySource<?>> propertySourceList = (new YamlPropertySourceLoader()).load(resource.getResource().getFilename(), resource.getResource());
            return !propertySourceList.isEmpty() ? (PropertySource)propertySourceList.iterator().next() : super.createPropertySource(name, resource);
        }
    }
}
```